# Can I send requests to an express app directly, rather than via http?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, express

I have a file that creates an express server.  Let's call it `foo_serever.coffee`

```
# foo_server.coffee
module.exports = express.createServer()
```

And now I want to require that and send it requests directly in javascript. (Note, `sendRequest` is not a real method I just want one like it)

```
app = require './foo_server'
app.sendRequest 'get', '/some/url.html', (status, body, headers) ->
  console.log 'yay' if status is 200
```

Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to spawn it as another process and send it requests over http which seems like much more of a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Express only works as a real HTTP server, not a simulated one. Use a library like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) for testing. You don't have to spawn a separate process to send HTTP requests.

Comment: *Slaps forehead*. I don't know why I thought I needed to spawn a process. And thanks for the link to request.  Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As Trevor said you can use Mikeal's [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library for testing or Learnboost's [Tobi](https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi) if you want to do 'Expressive server-side functional testing with jQuery'.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't as elegant as doing it through the express frame work but I know that the Nodejs http module allows for making http requests to any site, and allows you to supply the headers and host ect.

See the node http documentation for details and examples.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/http.html#http.get

Comment: Well that is my backup plan, I guess.  But it just seems silly to launch a JS powered server on a port, just so that I can make requests from JS and run some JS in response.

Comment: You are not creating a js server. You are requiring the http module and then using one of the methods it exports.